# How to Perform left Anti and Right Antijoins in Dataflow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I can see i can do only

Left right inner,Full ,Cross joins in Dataflow.
I can t see a left Anti or Right Anti joins in Dataflow. So how to perform those joins like that of in Sql in Azure data factory

Comment: You can use join conditions in left, right inner, full, cross joins in dataflow to perform anti joins. Refer this document it may helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join

Comment: Like what need to be done ,i cant find any conditions for anti joins in the link provided .Is it selecting left outer join and giving condition as Col1 != Col2  .Please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As mentioned in [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join) you can able to see built in joins and perform Full outer, inner, Left outer, Right outer and Cross joins in Data flow as shown in below image.
[image]
But as per your requirement you can't see built in anti joins like left anti join, right anti join in data flow like SQL.
For anti joins in Data flow we can perform join conditions as shown in below image.
[image]
In join conditions what you have to do is as shown in below image from left column select source1 and from  right column select souce2 and in between  there is filter operation like [= =,! =,<,>, <=,>=, = = =, < = > ].As per our requirement we can perform any of these operations in left join.
[image]
I created data flow as shown below by taking source1 as employee data and source2 as depart and combined these sources using left join.
[image]
After choosing left join in join conditions column1 as employee data and column2 as depart and in filter i am using === operator
[image]
After performing left join and join condition below is the output got.
[image]

Here is the Source1= employee data input:

[image]

Sorce 2= depart input:
[image]

Alternative method:

As of now it is not possible in joins but you can try it by using Exists.

Source1 in dataflow

[image]

Source2 data in dataflow

[image]

Next both sources are joined by EXIST activity. In below image you can find exist type & exists conditions. In Exist Activity Exist type is Doesn't exist
[image]

After validation you can see required left anti join output in Data preview as shown below
[image]

Comment: === or any other operator doesnot give me Left or right Anti joins output. === is just including Null matching rows to be included along with matched rows

Comment: Please help me with the condition for Left anti join to be given in the join condition in dataflow.

Comment: AFAIK, in ADF joins anti left is not present. You can do it with by first taking left outer join and inner join to files. Then use look up activity in ADF and use filter activity for not exist. then you can get left anti join output.

Comment: Cant we do it within data flow ?

Comment: Half with dataflow and half with ADF is possible as of now

Comment: @Surya Teja532 with in data  flow you can try it by using Exists. Edited the answer by using Exists check once edited solution

Comment: I think only left Anti Join is possible with doesnot exists option in Exists transformation ,but Rigut Anti join and Smei Anti not possible ?

Comment: Yes only left anti join is possible with Exists transformation remaining anti joins are not possible as of now.